# How to detect if in the catch block of a Promise

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, callback

I've written some absurdly simple error-handling code that works flawlessly with synchronous operations. I had to modify the `throwError` function to behave how I want with asynchronous operations, but now it doesn't work as I expect with synchronous operations. How can I detect if the function is being called in the catch block of a Promise or not to change the behavior?

Here's the code that works well for sync operations:

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Woot, handled error')
const throwError = (error) => {
  throw error
}

try {
  throwError(new Error('Blah blah'))
  console.log('This should not be reached')
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```

Here's the code that's great for async operations:

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Blah blah')
const throwError = (error) => {
  errorHandler(error)
}

const loadStuff = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  console.log('Loading stuff')
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oh no, an error!')), 1000)
})

try {
  loadStuff().catch(throwError)
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```

But if you put the async `throwError` code in the sync code the second console.log executes. If you put the sync `throwError` in the async code it gives an unhanded promise rejection error.

How can I, with only one `throwError` function, know if it's catching a Promise or being manually called to switch between calling `errorHandler` directly and `throw`ing the error? Assume that only `throwError` and the last `catch` clause can access `errorHandler`.

This question was hard to write for some reason and is probably phrased all weird, I'd appreciate any clarifying edits.

Comment: It is a little hard to figure out what you're after because the code looks like it's working. What is the result you want in the second example? What should be written to the console?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The second example is also working fine. The problem is I want there to only be one `throwError` function that works for both examples.

Comment: It seems your actual problem is not how to write `throwError` so that it works in both cases, but rather that you are doing the asynchronous error handling wrong. Don't do both `try`/`catch` and `.catch()`, use *only* promise error handling - either through `await` or through `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

> But if you put the async throwError code in the sync code the second console.log executes. If you put the sync throwError in the async code it gives an unhanded promise rejection error.

Is that maybe a few things should be clarified beforehand, the two functions *throwError* you wrote do completely different things as one receives an error and throws it, and the other one just logs *'Blah blah'*.

On the other hand in the code

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Blah blah')
const throwError = (error) => {
  errorHandler(error)
}

const loadStuff = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  console.log('Loading stuff')
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oh no, an error!')), 1000)
})

try {
  loadStuff().catch(throwError)
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```

If we change the throwError function to be equal as the first one, then the code would look like this:

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Blah blah')
const throwError = (error) => {
   throw error
}

const loadStuff = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  console.log('Loading stuff')
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oh no, an error!')), 1000)
})

try {
  loadStuff().catch(throwError)
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```

And what happens here is that once loadStuff is rejected then the throwError function is executed so an error is thrown, but it won't be catched in the try/catch statement as the statements within the *try* don't throw an error as loadStuff just returns a promise, *what happens in the catch of loadStuff has nothing to do with the catch of the try/catch* as it has a different [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) . In fact both catches could be executed at the same time if it written like this:

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Blah blah')
const throwError = (error) => {
   console.log('another catch')
   throw error
}

const loadStuff = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  console.log('Loading stuff')
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oh no, an error!')), 1000)
})

try {
  loadStuff().catch(throwError)
  throw new Error('my Error')
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```

Having said that and **assuming** everytime an error is thrown you want to handle it the same way a possible solution would be to just write it as this:

```js
const errorHandler = () => console.log('Blah blah')

const loadStuff = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  console.log('Loading stuff')
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oh no, an error!')), 1000)
})

try {
  loadStuff().catch(errorHandler)
} catch(error) {
  errorHandler(error)
}
```